# Set cookie while loading remote js in the domain where js is hosted

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-domain

Below is the scenario am looking at:

1. I am remotely loading a js file to the site `hello.com`.
2. The js is loaded from `jsfoo.com`.
3. I want to set a cookie for the domain jsfoo.com in the users browser   when the user the is visiting `hello.com`?

Is it something possible from within the js file that is loaded or do I have to write a server side logic when loading the js?

**The objective** is to retarget the user who visited `hello.com` when the user vists `jsfoo.com` later.

Update based on the comment below:
Would it possible if js is loaded dynamically? For example if we load the js via a dynamic url like jsfoo.com/getjs.php?js=sample.js. Wouldn't it be possible for the code to set and get the cookies for jsfoo.com via php code?

Comment: The JS code is executed under your domain. This is only possible if the script resource loaded from the other domain sets a cookie for that domain via the HTTP response header.

Comment: @CBroe you mean on the server side? For example imagine if am loading the js via jsfoo.com/getjs.php?js=sample.js. Wouldn't it be possible for me to set and get the cookies for jsfoo.com via php code?

Comment: Yes, it needs to happen server-side.

Comment: So now if I need to get the cookie value of `jsfoo.com` in `hello.com`, I will need to have the cookie value loaded inside the dynamic js that is loaded from the server side, correct? @CBroe

Comment: You won’t be able to _access_ the cookie of jsfoo.com in hello.com. If you need the existing value, then your script on jsfoo needs to read it when the request to its domain happens, and return the value in a way that JS can read it (f.e. by outputting it as a JS variable.)

Comment: @CBroe If you can make the above details as an answer, I can accept it as the right one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JS code is executed under your domain, so you can not set that cookie client-side. This is only possible if the script resource loaded from the other domain sets a cookie for that domain via the HTTP response header.

And you won’t be able to access the cookie of jsfoo.com in hello.com. If you need the existing value, then your script on jsfoo needs to read it when the request to its domain happens, and return the value in a way that JS can read it (f.e. by outputting it as a JS variable.)

Comment: Thanks. Have marked it as the answer. Did help me clear the idea. Especially the remote js part.